# Getting list content via Casper JS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using the CasperJS to grab the list data on the website.
I've already finished the part of login and screenshot, I make sure that I am on the page which i want to grab.

Here is the list like this

```
<ul id='list'>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And I use the code below

```
casper.thenOpen(url, 
function () {
        this.capture('project/targetPage.png') // CapScreen
    });


    var ulList = casper.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelectorAll('ul#list > li') // Get List
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        var arr = [];
        ulList.forEach(function (v) { // Use the list to loop
            arr.push(v.innerText)
        });
        this.echo(arr);
    });
```

and I got this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 
    'ulList.forEach(function (v) {
        arr.push(v.innerText)
     })')
```

I just want the simple array like this

```
 ['item1','item2']
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you do `console.log(ulList)` after `var ulList = casper.evaluate(...)`, what does that show?

Comment: @JackBashford a very very long object, include the whole html code and the webkit data(?). I'm not sure what is that but the result is different with you type `document.querySelectorAll('ul#list > li')` in the browser console

Comment: What are you trying to iterate over with `ulList.foreach`? If it's an object, you'd need to use a static method to get an iterable collection first.

Comment: I use   `console.log(ulList.length)

    for(var i = 0; i < ulList.length;i++){
        console.log(ulList[i].innerHTML)
    }` , the length return 5 , but error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ulList[i].innerHTML')   `

Comment: I try to use `document.querySelectorAll('ul#pbbs > li')[1].innerHTML`, it works on console but not works in casper JS.